# Change location of /etc/fstab

Tags: linux, bash, shell, fstab

I have written a script which requires to read a few entries in `/etc/fstab`. I have tested the script by manually adding some entries in `/etc/fstab` and then restored the file to its original contents, also manually. Now I would like to automate those tests and run them as a seperate script. I do, however, not feel comfortable with the idea of changing `/etc/fstab` altered. I was thinking of making a backup copy of `/etc/fstab`, then altering it and finally restoring the original file after the tests are done. I would prefer it if I could temporarily alter the location of `fstab`.

Is there a way to alter the location of `fstab` to, say, `/usr/local/etc/fstab` so that when `mount -a` is run from within a script only the entries in `/usr/local/etc/fstab` are processed?

**UPDATE:**

I used [bishop's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384721/change-location-of-etc-fstab/41384825#41384825) by setting `LIBMOUNT_FSTAB=/usr/local/etc/fstab`. I have skimmed the man page of `mount` on several occasions in the past but I never noticed this variable. I am not sure if this variable has always been there and I simply overlooked it or if it had been added at some point. I am using `mount from util-linux 2.27.1` and at least in this version `LIBMOUNT_FSTAB` is available and documented in the man-page. It is in the `ENVIRONMENT` section at the end. This will make my automated tests a lot safer in the future.

**UPDATE2:**

Since there has been some discussion whether this is an appropriate programming question or not, I have decided to write a small script which demonstrates the usage of LIBMOUNT_FSTAB.

```
#!/bin/bash

libmount=libmount_fstab
tmpdir="/tmp/test_${libmount}_folder" # temporary test folder
mntdir="$tmpdir/test_${libmount}_mountfolder" # mount folder for loop device
img="$tmpdir/loop.img" # dummy image for loop device
faketab="$tmpdir/alternate_fstab" # temporary, alternative fstab

# get first free loop device
loopdev=$(losetup -f)

# verify there is a free loop device
if [[ -z "$loopdev" ]];then
    echo "Error: No free loop device" >&2
    exit 1
fi

# check that loop device is not managed by default /etc/fstab
if grep "^$loopdev" /etc/fstab ;then
    echo "Error: $loopdev already managed by /etc/fstab" >&2
    exit 1
fi

# make temp folders
mkdir -p "$tmpdir"
mkdir -p "$mntdir"

# create temporary, alternative fstab
echo "$loopdev $mntdir ext2 errors=remount-ro 0 1" > "$faketab"

# create dummy image for loop device
dd if=/dev/zero of="$img" bs=1M count=5 &>/dev/null

# setup loop device with dummy image
losetup "$loopdev" "$img" &>/dev/null

# format loop device so it can be mounted
mke2fs "$loopdev" &>/dev/null

# alter location for fstab
export LIBMOUNT_FSTAB="$faketab"

# mount loop device by using alternative fstab
mount "$loopdev" &>/dev/null

# verify loop device was successfully mounted
if mount | grep "^$loopdev" &>/dev/null;then
    echo "Successfully used alternative fstab: $faketab"
else
    echo "Failed to use alternative fstab: $faketab"
fi

# clean up
umount "$loopdev" &>/dev/null
losetup -d "$loopdev"
rm -rf "$tmpdir"

exit 0
```

My script primarily manages external devices which are not attached most of the time. I use loop-devices to simulate external devices to test the functionality of my script. This saves a lot of time since I do not have to attach/reattach several physical devices. I think this proves that being able to use an alternative `fstab` is a very useful feature and allows for scripting safe test scenarios whenever parsing/altering of `fstab` is required. In fact, I have decided to partially rewrite my script so that it can also use an alternative `fstab`. Since most of the external devices are hardly ever attached to the system their corresponding entries are just cluttering up `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: SO is for programming questions. Unix.SE would be a better place to ask questions about configuring Unix.

Comment: That sounds like doing it backwards to me. Make your script take the location from an environment variable (using `/etc/fstab` if unset).

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to tell `mount` to use an alternate location for `fstab`.

Comment: @Barmar This *is* a programming question (testing methodology, particularly).

Comment: @bishop "Is there a way to alter the location of fstab" is not a question about testing methodology. If the question asked how to make his script examine a copy of `/etc/fstab`, that would be on-topic.

Comment: @Barmar Part of answering questions is guiding people to ask the right questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor your code that modifies fstab contents into a single function, then test that function correctly modifies the dummy fstab files you provide it. Then you can confidently use that function as part of your `mount` pipeline.

```
function change_fstab {
    local fstab_path=${1:?Supply a path to the fstab file}
    # ... etc
}

change_fstab /etc/fstab && mount ...
```

Alternatively, set `LIBMOUNT_FSTAB` per [the libmount docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.26/libmount-docs/libmount-Utils.html#mnt-get-fstab-path):

```
LIBMOUNT_FSTAB=/path/to/fake/fstab mount ...
```

Comment: I don't see anything in the `mount(8)` man page that says it uses that environment variable. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Barmar I used the source code. mount.c uses libmount, and libmount uses it. Mileage may vary outside GNU/Linux. Centos man page, incidentally, says under `"ENVIRONMENT": LIBMOUNT_FSTAB=<path> overrides the default location of the fstab file`

Comment: Maybe it depends on the distribution. I'm on Debian 7 and don't see that in the man page. But `ldd /bin/mount` does show it using `libmount`, so it might work.

Comment: Perfect! I was looking for exactly this kind of solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, Debian. Could be. For me, `strace mount -v 2>&1 | grep -i libmount` yields `open("/lib64/libmount.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3` and `strings /lib64/libmount.so.1 | grep -i libmount_fstab` yields `LIBMOUNT_FSTAB`, plus evidence of man page and reading the source, I'm certain it's *supposed* to work on my box. I'll save myself the trouble of mount gymnastics right now. :)

Comment: @Barmar Try this: `sudo -i; mount -v; touch /tmp/mtab; export LIBMOUNT_MTAB=/tmp/mtab; mount -v; exit` If that later mount shows empty, then LIBMOUNT environment variables are *probably* in play.

Comment: @bishop I don't have a Linux system I can play with like that, so I'll have to remain ignorant about how it works on my system.

Comment: @Barmar didn't you say earlier that you are using Debian 7? Btw, I tried it and it works.

Comment: @nautical I have a Linux system, but I don't think I can modify its mount table, it will affect other users. It's not my personal system.

Comment: @Barmar that is exactly what `LIBMOUNT_FSTAB` is meant for. You can use it to set an alternative `fstab`, e.g.,  `/usr/local/etc/fstab` and only those entries will be processed in the current CLI session, exclusivly. If you use it as bishop suggested, i.e., `LIBMOUNT_FSTAB=/usr/local/etc/fstab mount ...` then only this single mount operation will be affected. The original `/etc/fstab` is *never* touched and will be used by the rest of the system regardless of the current setting in the current terminal. I used loop devices to verify the behavior.

Comment: The envirionment variable just tells it where to get the configuration data to use. The entire system will still be affected by the mount changes that I make from that alternate file.

Comment: @Barmar You can have a look at my updated question. I have added a script to demonstrate how to leverage the $LIBMOUNT_FSTAB variable. If the system you are using does not use loop-devices it is probabaly safe to give it a try. I am assuming/expecting that you have the required knowledge to assess if the demo script will have any impact on your system.